# Use VLOOKUP with split ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm making a formula that looks up a value and returns a value, fairly simple procedure as I can use `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX-MATCH`. However, I cannot seem to create or find a way to make it work when the ranges are located side by side. (Will provide example)

I know I could move all the data into two columns, but that would make it Very long and the table is often looked at for reference. I would like to keep the table the way it is.

What I am looking for is that I can type the tank level(inches) into a cell and next to it it will return the tank level(gallons).
My current formula is

```
=INDEX('Calib. A & B'!$B$3:$B$47,MATCH(TANKS!$E$2,'Calib. A & B'!$A$3:$A$47,1))
```

Currently it compares cell `E2` with `A3:A47` and returns the corresponding value in `B3:B47`. It needs to search columns C, E, G, I, etc. Any ideas other than rearranging the spreadsheet?

[image]

Comment: If I were you I will probably create a 2-Column table in a separate worksheet and use **INDEX+MATCH** to find the volume. There is an option to do the look up using `#powerquery` but the idea is essentially the same, convert the current table into a 2-Column one and then use some filter function to get the desired result. The downfall is that every time you are looking for a new depth you need to refresh the output/worksheet to get an updated result. Not as instant as using formula as illustrated by RonRosenfeld.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of obtaining the relevant rows/columns for the lookup:

```
=INDEX('Calib. A & B'!$A$3:$U$47,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((TANKS!$E$2='Calib. A & B'!$A$3:$U$47))*ROW('Calib. A & B'!$A$3:$U$47)-2,1),AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(TANKS!$E$2='Calib. A & B'!$A$3:$U$47)*COLUMN('Calib. A & B'!$A$3:$U$47)+1,1))
```

The `-2` for the rows argument of the index function is to adjust for the header position.
The `+1` for the columns argument is to return the value one column to the right of the cell that matched.

This assumes, of course, that the values matching the lookup_value in `E2` are only found in the "odd" columns of the data range.

As suggested by @TerryW, if your measure in `E2` is not an exact match to the value in the data table (and the data table measurements are exact to the 1/8), you can roundup E2 to the next 1/8th.

Replace `TANKS!$E$2` with `ROUNDUP(TANKS!$E$2*8,0)/8`

Comment: your answer will work if it is exact match but it seems that the OP was trying to do a `less than` match

Comment: @TerryW If that's what he wants, all he needs to do is roundup E2 to the next 1/8th. I'll add that to my answer with credit.

Answer (score 0):

One way is with a long formula basically doing a union of results of the match on each column but having result as empty string when do not match it.

So we do a match against column A, if it doesn't find it it returns a blank string, if it finds it returns the number , then does the same for column C and concatenates the results and uses this on the index.

BUT this will only work if you search for an exact match.

For example:

```
=INDEX('Calib. A & B'!$B$3:$B$47,IF(ISNA(MATCH(TANKS!$E$2,'Calib. A & B'!$A$3:$A$47,0)),"",MATCH(TANKS!$E$2,'Calib. A & B'!$A$3:$A$47))&IF(ISNA(MATCH(MATCH(TANKS!$E$2,'Calib. A & B'!$C$3:$C$47,0)),"",MATCH(MATCH(TANKS!$E$2,'Calib. A & B'!$C$3:$C$47)))
```

You would need to add one more section for each column.